# Python get function name after initiating by type

Tags: python

What can I do to get "get1" as the output rather than "get" when i call h.get1()

```py
import inspect

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base.")


def get(self):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    print(inspect.getframeinfo(frame).function)  # which prints "get".
    print("get method.")


dic = {}

dic.setdefault("get1", get)
Hello = type("ABC", (Base,), dic)
h = Hello()
h.get1()   # which invokes get()
```

Comment: You'd have to look it up in the `dic`, because the `inspect.getframeinfo` won't give you any knowledge of what key in a dict `get` is being referred to by

Comment: So, you could look through `type(self)`, e.g. `for k,v in vars(type(self)).items(): if v is get: print(k)` all of this will be very brittle. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: hi @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for your advice : ). here are some goals i would like to achive. 1. create a dynamic class. 2. add dynamic functions into class which could be created by function templates. 3. each method should know its own custom name. so i think ```if v is get: print(k)``` this will make templates non reusable.

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution then is to just use `exec` to create the class from a template, or at least the functions, because that's the only way the function will know it's `.name`. Using he function constructor is quite difficult and not worth it, just use `exec`

Comment: But you really should add more details to your actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than messing with frames, you could just use a simple class that carry your key name. For example:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base.")

class Getter:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __call__(self):
        print(f'Getter for {self.key} has been called.')

dic = {}

dic.setdefault("get1", Getter('get1'))
Hello = type("ABC", (Base,), dic)
h = Hello()
h.get1()   # which invokes get()
```

Which would prints:

```
Getter for get1 has been called.
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment, I'm still unsure what you are trying to do but you could use a wrapper scope to retrieve the name from the back frame I guess. For example:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps

class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base.")

def make_wrapper(name, func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal name
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

def get(self):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    print(frame.f_back.f_locals.get('name', 'Unknown'))  # which prints "get1".

dic = {}

dic.setdefault("get1", make_wrapper('get1', get))
Hello = type("ABC", (Base,), dic)
h = Hello()
h.get1()   # which invokes get()
```

**EDIT by child2d**
Bravo! I have come up with a simple way to solve it based on your advise.
btw module inspect is not really need, sorry for the misunderstanding.

here is my simplified solution just for my own scenario.

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self):
        print("base.")

def method_generator(custom_method_name):
    def get(self):
        print(custom_method_name) # which is a dynamic name.
        # do_something()

    return get

dic = {}

dic.setdefault("get1", method_generator('get1'))
Hello = type("ABC", (Base,), dic)
h = Hello()
h.get1()   # which invokes get()
```

thanks so much! ^_^

Comment: thanks jordan for your solution. actually i am trying to create dynamic api test cases generated by function templates using locust.io.  it requires us to define test logic in function rather than a new class. so a Getter class may not be suitable for me.

Comment: So you need to be able to pass existing functions?

Comment: Edited my answer with a possible solution, other than that I have no other ideas with your current code.